# Where should I put test cases for Groovy classes in a Grails app?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I have a couple of Groovy classes in my app, under `src/groovy`.  Where should the associated test classes go, and should they use the `GroovyTestCase` or the mixins(`TestFor`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose between a unit or integration test for your class. From the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html) you can see the difference between them:

**Unit Test**

> Unit testing are tests at the "unit" level. In other words you are
>   testing individual methods or blocks of code without consideration for
>   surrounding infrastructure. Unit tests are typically run without the
>   presence of physical resources that involve I/O such databases, socket
>   connections or files. This is to ensure they run as quick as possible
>   since quick feedback is important.

**Integration Test**

> Integration tests differ from unit tests in that you have full access
>   to the Grails environment within the test.

So if you need to access the database or need the full environment, do a integration test. If not, create a unit test (this will use a in-memory database).

The `@TestFor` is intended to use in unit tests, since this will mock the basic (see `GrailsUnitTestMixin`). If you choose the integration test, don't use the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in `test/unit`.  If they need a spring context or hibernate session, put them in `test/integration`.  You can use `GroovyTestCase` or the mixins, but they are completely optional.  The tests only need to follow the following conventions:

- the class name must end with `Tests` or `Test`
- the test methods must either begin with `test` or be annotated with JUnit's `@Test` annotation